# Error creating json file in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have followed many solutions provided in the previous questions but mine is not working. The problem is in .json extension. Whenever I use **filename.json**, the app will crash with ERR_CONNECTION_RESET but successfully created an empty .json file. However, if I change the extension to **filename.txt**, the fs.writeFile will successfully create the filename.txt with the data inside and the app will work as expected. Did I miss any configuration here to create the JSON file?
Here is the example code I used.

```
var jsonData = '{"persons":[{"name":"John","city":"New York"},{"name":"Phil","city":"Ohio"}]}';

// parse json
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonData);
console.log(jsonObj);

// stringify JSON Object
var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonContent);

fs.writeFile("./public/output.json", jsonContent, 'utf8', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("An error occured while writing JSON Object to File.");
    return console.log(err);
  }

  console.log("JSON file has been saved.");
});
```

Comment: i tested the code you show, it works on my side.

Comment: Are you using a live reload server? Because if that's the case, the live-server will track for `.json` changes and if it finds a new file create event, it'll restart the Node application, hence closing the thread.

Comment: @Dean Yeah, that's strange! I am not sure what's wrong with my nodejs app.

Comment: @weirdpanda I am only using nodemon. Could it be the problem?

Comment: @striplingboy, yeah! I guess that's the problem. Try excluding `--ignore public/**/*.json` That should be helpful for debugging.

Comment: @weirdpanda 대박! It works perfectly! I never expect that nodemon could be the problem. Thank you :D

Comment: @weirdpanda now how to close this question? Or you can answer the question and I will accept the answer. This is my first question lol.

Comment: @striplingboy, added the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` means that the connection was closed midway. My guess, as in the comments, would be that it's a reloading server.

Try using `--ignore public/**/*.json` and it should work.